# Console login when password contains British Pound Sterling (£) character

Tags: keyboard, terminal, login

When setting up my Pi, I set my password before changing the keyboard type and layout and rebooting. My password now contains a British Pound Sterling (£) symbol where I had intended to type an octothorpe/hash (#). How do I now type "£" at the console to log in when there is no such key on my keyboard? I've tried Alt+163 and Alt+0163 (using the num pad) but nothing appears (Alt+35 does produce a "#" character, however).

Comment: Scrub that SDCard, write a fresh copy of RaspiOS to it and start again.

Comment: I've resolved the problem by mounting the SD card on another computer, mounting the root filesystem, and deleting the contents of the password field in /etc/shadow. Still, I'm curious to know how to enter non-typeable characters at the console (how to type "#" with the default UK keyboard layout being a common scenario); presumably the supported range of Alt codes is very limited.

Comment: In theory no, since console alt codes are just [UTF8 values in decimal](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec).  How well they work in practice I can't say...

Answer (score 4):

To have a decent answer, here is it what the questioner posted in a comment:

> I've resolved the problem by mounting the SD card on another computer, mounting the root filesystem, and deleting the contents of the password field in /etc/shadow. Still, I'm curious to know how to enter non-typeable characters at the console (how to type "#" with the default UK keyboard layout being a common scenario); presumably the supported range of Alt codes is very limited.